# multiple addresses for ethereum wallet

Tags: wallets, addresses, exchanges

Creating smth like a crypto broker and faced problem - erc-20 wallets does not support multi addresses. For example bitcoin wallets provide opportunity to create a lot of public keys, so we can make a unique key for every user and all of them will be linked to 1 wallet, it is necessary so that we are able to identify a client sending us crypto.

However erc-20 does not support multi addresses and it seems like we will have to create a separate wallet (on our side) for each user, so that we are able to identify him. Is there any solution to this problem and how is it implemented on crypto exchanges?

Comment: There's multiple possible approaches to the problem, for example https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82479/how-do-exchanges-work-internally, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46218/using-hd-wallet-for-exchange-customer, or use a contract as wallet.

Comment: Does hd wallet actually provides opportunity to gather all funds deposited to different generated public addresses on a common wallet?

Comment: I mean paying fee for moving all funds from different addresses just once

Comment: No, each address is its own account. Ethereum uses the account model, it doesn't have the concept of UTXO. See the differences  here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/326/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-ethereum-balances-vs-utxos.